# Can't insert data into my database using wamp server and php

Tags: mysql, android-studio, wamp

It gives me this error:

> Error: insert into employee_data (name, surname, age, username,
>   password values ('agag','agag','22','abc','abc') You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'values
>   ('agag','agag','22','abc','abc')' at line 1

When i tested this code:

[image]

I'm using wamp server and notepad++ for coding.
Please help me im going so hard on this project for my school, would appreciate all help.

[testing if data as been inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr5cc.png)

Comment: You missed to close parenthesis after `password`.

Comment: Tpjoka your right i did changed it now, but still gives me that error

Comment: Never mind Tpojka , it is working, the error was that parenthesis after all. Thank you so much, im working in a project for school and you just helped me ^^ How can i tumbs you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like syntax error. 
On image you posted, it looks like parenthesis after `password` is forgotten. 
Closing it should be ok. 
Also, I would like to mention you that beside the images posting actual code is best way one could get to try help and solve issue. Check [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask best way.

```
INSERT INTO `employee_data` (`name`, `surname`, `age`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('agag','agag','22','abc','abc');
```

Also, pay attention on having variables like tables/columns name wrapped with backticks and other security matters.

Comment: I tried to insert the code i even did Ctrl+K but it gived me an error, had to put those 2 images. I also thinked that putting the code here would be better for who would going to answer to my question. Thank you Tpojka.

Comment: Tpojka could you give it an eye to this link ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096456/cant-insert-data-into-my-database-using-wamp-server-php

Comment: I thought problem is solved so I offered answer? I am not sure what `Ctrl+K` is. What happened when you updated syntax as I proposed?

Comment: Yes yes, problem is solved ! Thank you !
 I was saying that to put some  code here you gotta press Ctr+K to insert your code otherwise it gives an error when i try to publich a question

Comment: I edited answer if you meant that one. It would be much appreciated to you accept answer so others with same problem could find out solution here. Happy coding. ;)

Comment: i didnt saw it, what do you mean by accepting the answers? Im new to this website. I dont know how this community works.
 I would like to share this topic so people with same problem could see how problem is solved.